# Mathematics behind Incentive Design

Tags: game-theory, economics

I was working on an Applied Math project on allocation and I had an interesting idea about extending it to providing incentives to different "players" in the allocation process.

But I am clueless about **how** incentives are designed. For instance, if I had 2 tickets to a football game and 5 people that I am trying to allocate to (2 get 1 each), how do I provide incentives for someone who doesn't really want to go to say no and stuff (basically, ensure that the "best" 2 actually get the tickets).

I just want to know where should I get started on reading about this. I understand this is probably under Game Theory and probably a subpart of Mechanism Design but is there a specialized field of Math/Econ for designing incentives?

Comment: A simple way to figure this in is to provide a valuation for utility (how much satisfaction a person gets from going to the football game).
Taking your football tickets example, suppose that the players value the tickets at $v_i$. You can rank these valuations from lowest to highest. 
Just set the price of the tickets such that $v_2>price>v_3$

Another thing you may want to look into is second price auctions. That may also prove to be insightful.

Comment: @Jordan. Interesting insight but here's the catch: I am not selling those tickets. Assume I am a non-profit who wants to distribute these tickets. How do I provide incentives to people to reject if they are not interested/if they are uncertain they can't make it? (This would probably make more sense if I had something like blankets or food but whatever, you get the point).

Comment: Is it possible to introduce transactions costs?
So in order to get the tickets, you have to travel 10km to collect them. This has a transaction cost which we will call T.
This gives the same conclusion as the price, though more subtly.

Comment: @Jordan. Can't do that either. Picture this exact situation: I am in earthquake devastated regions (some are worse hit than others). Suppose I run a distribution center and there is a queue of people waiting for food. Assume that each person wishes to take away enough food to feed his entire family. How do I provide incentive to a person in the queue to tell me an un-exaggerated estimate of his/her family's needs? I don't want an answer to this question but rather a direction to start exploring. What subfield of math/econ would this come under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the area you are interested in is Information Economics.

There is a subpart of information economics, called Screening. 
Screening is essentially about how an uninformed agent can get an informed agent to provide truthful information about themselves.